# Invalid Syntax (For Loop brackets/parentheses)

Tags: python, syntax-error

The following line of code outputs `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
for (i in range(-WIDTH,WIDTH)):
```

The next one works without errors. I have no idea what the syntax error is supposed to be here. So I am just asking out of curiosity. My guess is that the brackets prevent the expression from being evaluated.

```
for i in range(-WIDTH,WIDTH):
```

Comment: @cricket_007 OP might be from the UK, where it's pretty common to call `()` brackets.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist  `(   )` are called brackets in the UK, Canada, New Zealand, and Australia.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket.  Having said that, anyone who has been in programming for any length of time internationally use the terms "parentheses" and "square brackets".  Newbies need to be told which words to be avoid - it does not come naturally.  Don't get me started on #.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your parentheses are essentially just confusing the parser.

There are a couple of reasons you could have an open paren after a `for`, most notably using tuple unpacking:

```
>>> for (x, y) in zip(range(5), range(6, 11)):
...   print(x, '->', y)
... 
0 -> 6
1 -> 7
2 -> 8
3 -> 9
4 -> 10
```

Additionally, parens can be used in loads of places in Python for simple grouping, such as when breaking up long lines:

```
>>> s = ("This is "
... "a really awkward way "
... "to write a "
... "long string "
... "over several lines")
>>> 
>>> s
'This is a really awkward way to write a long string over several lines'
```

So the parser won't really complain about it.

However, as you know, `for` is [supposed to read like this](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

Which means that by grouping this way, you're constructing an invalid loop. Essentially, yours reads that there is no `in` because it's grouped into the `target_list` by your parentheses. Hope this makes sense.

---

A way to see more clearly what's happening: write the rest of your for loop (in `expression_list`) after your close paren. Then you will get a clearer error about how it is interpreting this statement.

```
>>> for (i in range(-WIDTH, WIDTH)) in range(-WIDTH, WIDTH):
...   print(i)
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to comparison
```

So it will let you do it, but the result of `x in y` will be a boolean, which cannot be the target of an assignment. The original error you got is because it got to your `:` before it found your `in`, which is plain old invalid syntax, as if you just wrote `for x:`.

Comment: The parentheses are *not* required in your first `for` loop: `for x, y in zip(range(5), range(6, 11)):`.  It is the comma that makes the tuple.  They are also used as the function call operator (contrast `x=foo` with `x=foo()` ).

Comment: I didn't say they were required. I said they were _allowed_. This is about how the parser thinks about the statements. I don't see how the function call usage could possibly be relevant, but I can add it to the answer if you tell me how.

Comment: Parentheses are allowed for precedence in many places.  You  mentioned tuple unpacking as "notable", but you rarely need them in tuple unpacking.   It is a common and easily made misconception that `[ ]` make lists therefore `( )` make tuples.  I take your point about function calls, I was just trying to think of places where using parentheses makes a difference.